# How to access Bootstrap from PHP code?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have table in PHP code, how to access Bootstrap from that table? I want to add table functionality of Bootstrap but my table is not in HTML it's in PHP. For table in html we use `<tr class="active">...</tr>`, how can I do this if my table is in PHP?

```
<?php
echo '<tr><td width="30%" style="text-transform:capitalize">'.$shArray[$i].'</td><td width="30%"><input type="text" value="'.$shArray[++$i].'"</input></td></tr>';
?>
```

Comment: i want to add table functionality of bootstarb but my table is not in html its in php. for table in html we use <tr class="active">...</tr>, how can i do this if my table is in php

Comment: PHP in your code produces HTML, so whatever you put in echo, it will be there: `echo '<tr class="active">...';`.

Comment: Seriously, who upvoted this question?

Comment: that i am doing , but i need to include bootstarap file in <?php file also ?

Comment: @gbestard thinking the same.

Comment: I think only you are understanding what you want to do. @anish

Comment: okay i am trying once again, see we can use bootstarap for table(which looks beeter as compared to normal table) for that we simply use           <tr class="warning"/ "success" etc.><td></td></tr>   but this is correcr if the table is in html tag, but i have created table in php tag using echo, how to use bootstrap facility in this case?   for eg refer: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_contextual&stacked=h

Comment: @anish Well, you must include bootstrap as you would do in any web page. In php you just have to output it, something like `echo '<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">';`. But your question is really misleading. There is no such thing as accessing bootsrap from php. Learn some basics about how those things work together, please.

Comment: And add this clarification to the question. It will help us to understand the issue.

Comment: (OP, the primary reason people express dissatisfaction for a question is not because it is "going over their head" - it is usually about either prior research or clarity. Please try to remain polite here, even if you are downvoted, and take any feedback given to improve your post. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

Add the bootstrap libraries to your page and simply add the class -

```
echo '<tr class="success"><td width="30%" style="text-transform:capitalize">'.$shArray[$i].'</td><td width="30%"><input type="text" value="'.$shArray[++$i].'"</input></td></tr>';
```

You can also use remaining class by changing the class name. You also have to add the `table` class to `table` tag. So that would be like -

```
echo '<table class="table">';
```

Just put the `'`/`"` carefully.

Comment: I'd say most of this can be rendered in HTML mode, breaking into PHP mode in short snippets for the two dynamic values.